# Android - press back button button, then return, but don't want re-create activity

Tags: android, android-activity

[My Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcuo111jkhwikga/Map11.rar)

It's my project, use Google Map API V2, have 2 Activity A & B . 
I have activity A - a list of area, if I choose one of them, Activity B show Google Map with a Marker . 
I want when I press back button, I return a list, choose anyone without re-created Activity B 
Please help me ... 
I have posted one question like this, but I really need the answer now :(

Answer (score 0):

basically when you app return to activity A, the onResume() part is invoked, but you can block  the recreation by simply declaring a static variable, declare it before oncreate as inited to false, then in oncreate make it true, and for recreation process use this as an if statement,

```
if(!myVar==true)
// your coding goes here
```

Comment: You is true, but if I press back button, then I click to one area, the activity B can't resume, It appears the activity B need onResume() and onCreate() .
I don't know how to pause activity B if I press back button

Comment: you can override onStop() or onPause() methods in activity B hence you can implement whatever you want inside them